# Web hook for sending gravity form submissions to Google a spreadsheet

Tags: wordpress, forms, action, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to get a gravity form to submit to a google docs spreadsheet. I found some code online for creating a web app and and action hook at https://ctrlq.org/code/20047-gravity-forms-to-google-spreadsheet

I have set up the web app but am having trouble with the Action hook. I have never used gravity forms and I don't know what to put in this section

```
// Put all the form fields (names and values) in this array
$body = array('name' => rgar($entry, '1'), 'age' => rgar($entry, '2'), 'sex' => rgar($entry, '3'),);
```

I am not sure what the names and values of the form fields are, are they the names and ids for the form fields or something else.

I know I can use the Zapier add on to do this but it's not my website and I can't just expect them to pay the fees.

Can anyone help me with this or is there a better solution? (there a 27 form fields that need to be sent.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The 'names' need to match the column headings you're using in your Google Sheet (i.e. 'city' in the example below). The ID's you can find by clicking on 'edit' in your Gravity Forms dashboard, and viewing the fields in your form using Chrome Dev Tools or similar. Each input will have an ID that looks like id="input_10", so for the example below the entry number is '10'.

```
'city' => rgar($entry, '10'),
```